# get a total value from loop items

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

Check the code bellow. I am looping to get all value of a returned XML response. But i want to get a total value of all `nofwatch` variable. How can i add them to get a total value? any idea?

```
foreach (var sri in searchResultItems)
{
    // Get all xml elements
    var childElements = sri.Elements();

    var nofwatch = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "listingInfo")
        .Elements().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "watchCount");

    //add items from xml data to EbayDataViewModel object
    items.Add(new EbayDataViewModel
    {
        TotalWatchers = nofwatch.Value //how can do + result of all nofwatch value?
    });

    ViewBag.TotalWatchers = TotalWatchers;
}
```

Comment: what type is `TotalWatchers` ? or `nofwatch.Value` ? usually you would have a sum variable declared outside of the loop. Then you would add the values up to this variable

Comment: May be this: `ViewBag.TotalWatchers += TotalWatchers`

Comment: Pretty sure Where clause and Sum could be enought. But can't be completly sure without a MCVE.

Comment: what is `TotalWatchers` ? is it only a property of `EbayDataViewModel` ? then your code should not compile... or is it a local or class variable? just having the same name as the property ?=!

Comment: Your question makes so sense. Please clarify what you mean.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
var totalValue = 0; //delcare the variable outside the foreach loop
foreach (var sri in searchResultItems)
{
    // Get all xml elements
    var childElements = sri.Elements();        
    var nofwatch = childElements.FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "listingInfo")
        .Elements().FirstOrDefault(x => x.Name.LocalName == "watchCount");

    //now use += operator to add the result to the totalValue variable
    //totalValue += nofwatch.Value;

    //nofwatch.Value should be of type string and you would need to parse it as an integer first if that truely is the case
    var intValue = 0;
    if (int.TryParse(nofwatch.Value, out intValue) == false)
        continue;

    totalValue += intValue;
}

//outside of the foreach loop use totalValue to set the desired member
ViewBag.TotalWatchers = totalValue;
```

Comment: What is the use of your `totalValue` variable? You are only assigning it.

Comment: Then you shouldn't answer but ask for clarification instead.

Comment: yes you are right. ViewBag.TotalWatchers = totalValue; @PatrickHofman

Comment: So why are you adding an item to the list for every time you loop then? Seems so unlogical to me. @JohnLk

Comment: Ok. however i just need ViewBag.TotalWatchers = totalValue; how can i achieve that? i just need to pass that value to my viewbag

Comment: @JohnLk So you dont need the line ``items.Add(...)``?

Comment: No i dont care it. i just need to pass the value to viewbag. @RandRandom

Comment: @JohnLk Than you can safely remove it.

Comment: @JohnLk did another edit since I believe that `nofwatch.Value` is a string and you would need an integer